# How to do Back order in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I am going to develop commerce drupal site.so i am also going to maintain stock.I have got commerce stock module for Stock management.But I do not know how to update quantity(Back Order) .Is there any module?Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the Commerce Stock module you need to do following to setup the initial stock for each products:

1. Visit admin/commerce/config/stock to enable stock tracking on your product type(s).
2. Set the starting value of stock on each product.

After setting the initial stock module will automatically do the following

1. Maintain stock levels
2. Implement validation of stock to prevent users from ordering out of stock items

For enhancing the module functionality you can create you custom rules using the Drupal [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.